# Creating an email newsletter using simplenews

Tags: 6, theming, emails

I need to create an email newsletter template using simplenews. Can anyone point me to a simple, clear tutorial on how to do so?

Comment: What's wrong with the [Simplenews handbook page](http://drupal.org/node/197057)?

Comment: Personally I found it to be rather incomplete and not as helpful as I would have hoped. Perhaps more advanced Drupal users may find it more useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this links useful

Designing a HTML newsletter for Drupal

http://drupalsteve.com/node/30

---

Drupal & Simplenews

http://www.slideshare.net/desk02/dug-simplenews-6192093

---

Email Newsletters and the Simplenews Module
http://www.group42.ca/email_newsletters_and_the_simplenews_module

---

and probably

Newsletter subscription management in Drupal with E-mail Marketing Framework

http://www.drupalcoder.com/blog/newsletter-subscription-management-in-drupal-with-e-mail-marketing-framework

Answer (score 1):

I had posted a similar question for D7 here [How to theme simplenews newsletters in D7?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11989/how-to-theme-simplenews-newsletters-in-d7)

and ran across the D6 version here:
http://drupal.org/node/197057